# Safe to blank MBR of a disk after adding it to an RAID1 array with mdadm?

Tags: raid, grub, mbr, mdadm, fdisk

I created a RAID1 array of two disks, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, using `mdadm`. After several booting problems related to the BIOS and SATA/RAID controller of the board, I accidently created some new partitions on `/dev/sda`, but didn't do any formating on those (`mkfs.ext4` complained).

Now I've got my installation, which is totally working fine, on `/dev/md127` with both partitions I created on the array, `md127p1` and `md127p2`. But I still see the partitions I created on /dev/sda accidently:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7e6506a6

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048  41945087  41943040    20G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       41945088 976773167 934828080 445.8G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/md127: 465.7 GiB, 499973619712 bytes, 976510976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd6cacd09

Device       Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/md127p1          2048  41945087  41943040    20G 83 Linux
/dev/md127p2      41945088 976510975 934565888 445.7G 83 Linux
```

This is probably because mdadm positions the superblock at 4K offset with the default metadata version 1.2, so the kernel still sees the MBR.

`lsblk` reports correctly, however:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─md127       9:127  0 465,7G  0 raid1 
├─md127p1 259:0    0    20G  0 md    /
└─md127p2 259:1    0 445,7G  0 md    /frzclient
sdb           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─md127       9:127  0 465,7G  0 raid1 
├─md127p1 259:0    0    20G  0 md    /
└─md127p2 259:1    0 445,7G  0 md    /frzclient
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Is it safe to just wipe the MBR with the bootloader and the partition table with zeros on `/dev/sda` and re-install GRUB in the MBR?